# Regex based routing setup for ingress in AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am have a K8s cluster in Azure, in which I am wanting to host multiple web applications on with a single host. Each application has it's own service and deployment. How can I achieve something like the following routes?

```
MyApp.com
Partner1.MyApp.com
Partner2.MyApp.com
```

Here is what my yml file looks like currently:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp # the label for the pods and the deployments
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myimagename
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6666 # the application listens to this port
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: myapp
spec:
    selector:
        app: myapp
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6666
      targetPort: 6666
    type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: partner1-myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: partner1-myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: partner1-myapp # the label for the pods and the deployments
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: partner1-myapp
        image: myimagename
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6669 # the application listens to this port
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: partner1-myapp
spec:
    selector:
        app: partner1-myapp
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6669
      targetPort: 6669
    type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: partner2-myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: partner2-myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: partner2-myapp # the label for the pods and the deployments
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: partner2-myapp
        image: myimagename
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6672# the application listens to this port
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: partner2-myapp
spec:
    selector:
        app: partner2-myapp
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6672
      targetPort: 6672
    type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 70m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: partner1-myapp
            port:
              number: 6669
 - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: partner2-myapp
            port:
              number: 6672
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp
            port:
              number: 6666
---
```

What can I do to get the above routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run your two applications using  `kubectl`

```
    kubectl apply -f Partner1-MyApp.yaml --namespace ingress-basic
    kubectl apply -f Partner2-MyApp.yaml --namespace ingress-basic
```

To setup for routing in your YAML file, If both application are running in Kubernetes cluster to route traffic in each application *EXTERNAL_IP/static* is needed to route the service, create a file name add this [YAML code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-powershell#run-demo-applications) in below

```
   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: partner-ingress-static
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /static/$2
    spec:
      ingressClassName: nginx
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - path: /static(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: partner1-myapp
                port: 
                  number: 6669
```

[image]

To more in detail please refer this link :

[Create an ingress controller in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-powershell)